# twitter oauth using R

Tags: r, twitter-oauth

I did all the steps

```
> library(ROAuth)
> reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
> accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
> authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
> consumerKey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
> consumerSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
> twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
+ consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
+ requestURL=reqURL,
+ accessURL=accessURL,
+ authURL=authURL)
> twitCred$handshake()
```

after that it told me to do this :

```
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=gYBR6Z2pg2YExfMjAsNp8QmjkSwpwfa5nPQNtUdgMWw
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here: registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
Error: Forbidden
```

I pasted my pin

```
> xyxabcd
```

it gave : 
    [1] xyxabcd

I typed my query

```
> delta.tweets = searchTwitter('@abcdx', n=1500)
```

but it gave this error again.

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : 
  OAuth authentication is required with Twitter's API v1.1
```

Comment: have a look at the `twitteR` and `httr` packages, maybe these are easier to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Dont use http but use https]**

You can follow this step:

```
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "Mjn6tdsadsadkasdklad2SV1l"
consumerSecret <- "58Z7Eldsdfaslkf;asldsaoeorjkfksaVCQtvri"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=reqURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake()
```

After you run this code you will see in R console message like this :

```
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=scmVODruosvz6Tdsdadadasdsa
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here:
```

Just paste the link to your browser then authorize app, last one you will get the PIN code, just copy and paste the PIN code to your R console.

```
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
```

R console will show TRUE if you success.

```
user <- getUser("xxx")
userTimeline(user, n=20, maxID=NULL, sinceID=NULL, includeRts=FALSE)
```

If still any problem just try to show your package version and update to the last version

```
sessionInfo()
update.packages("twitteR")
```

The last version for twitteR is 1.1.7 => http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/index.html

You can download twitteR manual => see page number 12 http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf

Answer (score 2):

First, if you were using RStudio or one of the other R GUIs, try re-running your `ROAuth` setup sequence from the R console instead. If you did do your setup that way originally or still have trouble after trying it from the console, then following [@Karsten W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216064/karsten-w)'s suggestion is the way to go.

You really should use the `devtools` version of `twitteR` available on [github](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR), and the following (which is just a mirror of the setup code example from Geoff's page) should get you going:

```
install.packages(c("devtools", "rjson", "bit64"))

# RESTART R SESSION

library(devtools)
install_github("httr")
install_github("twitteR", username="geoffjentry")
library(twitteR)
setup_twitter_oauth("API key", "API secret")
```

Comment: Error: could not find function "setup_twitter_auth" :(

Comment: It's `setup_twitter_oauth`, not `setup_twitter_auth`, and if you installed the github version of twitteR, it's there.

Comment: Ahh, I'm a moron, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Install packages 
install.packages("twitteR")
install.packages("RCurl")
install.packages(c("devtools", "rjson", "bit64", "httr"))
install_github("geoffjentry/twitteR")

#Load packages
require(twitteR)
require(RCurl)
library(devtools)

#Set variables
consumer_key <- 'you_key'
consumer_secret <- 'your_secret'
access_token <- 'your_token'
access_secret <- 'your_access'

#setup_twitter_oath with parameters
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

#searchTwitter function
ArduinoDaySA <- searchTwitter("ArduinoDaySA", n=3, lang="en")

ArduinoDaySA
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tried all the suggestions I found on the net but in vain. I tried this script and it worked for me like a beauty:

```
    options(httr_oauth_cache=T)

    api_key <- "XXXXX"

    api_secret <- "XXXXX"        

    access_token <- "XXXXX"         

    access_token_secret <- "XXXXX"

    setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
```

This works for me and hope it will for you.

Comment: had the same problem. Tried all the suggestions I found on the net but in vain. I tried this script and it worked for me like a beauty:

        options(httr_oauth_cache=T)

    api_key <- "XXXXX"

    api_secret <- "XXXXX"        

    access_token <- "XXXXX"         

    access_token_secret <- "XXXXX"

    setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)            
This works for me and hope it will for you.